# Geolocation open InfoWindow on load

Tags: 8, location

I can't get my head around the following. I'm using the Geolocation module to show a map on my website and I want the `InfoWindow` to be open by default.

I found that this should be possible by using the following code:
`infoWindow.open(map,marker);`

Or as the geolocation module does: `infoWindow.open(that.googleMap);`

But because I don't create the markers and infoWindows I don't know what there name is. I tried figuring it out by looking at the code of the Geolocation module by can't seem to find it out. How do I loop passed all `markers` en `infoWindows` to open them when the map is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging around in the module and decided to not build to loop but just use the one existing in the module. So I created a patch for Geolocation modules adding this line

```
currentInfoWindow.open(map.googleMap, currentMarker);
```

To line 83 of the `geolocation-marker-infowindow.js` file.